# Python Index out of range error, not sure why

Tags: python

Hello I am relatively new to programming and I am not sure why I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/ub62357.UBOC-AD/.PyCharmCE2017.1/config/scratches/scratch.py
3.1.1   Status of the 'Minimum Password Length' setting
Pass: 14 or greater
Fail: 13 or less, or missing
Found:set password-controls min-password-length

 line 42, in <module>
    print(x[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I understand that indexes start with 0. I thought I adjusted my code accordingly. I have a notepad file with 4 (0-3) fields delimited with |.

The code is supposed to search for the third index in another file and display the information associated with the other indexes once it finds that file.

Here is my code (minus the imports):

```
'''
I. Creates a list that stores the files in the folder where the configuration files are stored. Currently it is searching for all the text files
II. Loops through and opens that file so it can be tested.
'''
#creates a list to store the names of the configuration files to be tested
file_list = []
#fills the list with the files in the specified directory
for filename in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\ub62357.UBOC-AD\\Desktop\\FW ComplianceII\\Test Config\\'):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
           file_list.append(filename)
    # Creates comparison list
    Comparison_list = []
    # Opens the master file for comparison
    f_master = open('C:\\Users\\ub62357.UBOC-AD\\Desktop\\FW ComplianceII\\TSS_Script_List.txt', 'r')
    # Stores and splits the output and search information
    for line in f_master:
        holder = line.split("|")
        holder = [x.strip() for x in holder]
        Comparison_list.append(holder)
    # Loops through the files
    for i in range(len(file_list)):
        # appends the filename to the directory name and opens the file
        c_file = open('C:\\Users\\ub62357.UBOC-AD\\Desktop\\FW ComplianceII\\Test Config\\'+(file_list[i]))
        for x in Comparison_list:
               for line in c_file:
                    search_criteria = line.find(x[3])
                    if search_criteria == 0:
                        print(x[0])
                        print(x[1])
                        print(x[2])
                        print("Found:" + x[3])
        else:
            print(x[0])
            print(x[1])
            print(x[2])
            print("Line not found")
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I t would mean that `x` is a list with only one element. This happens most likely because in the lines where it's defined (by `holder`):

```
    holder = [x.strip() for x in holder]
    Comparison_list.append(holder)
```

`holder` is only of length 1 in some particular `line`. You can find it by adding

```
if len(holder)==1:
    `print(line)`
```